# Cypress PORT is returning undefined in integration testing (visual)

Tags: testing, environment-variables, integration-testing, port, cypress

How can I access the Cypress test running port in my test file? I am visual testing my application and I need to test different base URLs in a single script command. So I am planning to use `cy.visit(<base_ulr>:<port>')` directly in test file. But when I tried to access the PORT using env variable, `porcess.env.PORT`, its getting undefined. Anyone have any idea about this? Please need some help....

Answer (score 0):

If your port is defined as an environment variable, this is how you access Cypress environment variables:

```
Cypress.env('port') or Cypress.env().port
```

See doc [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env.html#Syntax)

Usually, you will define your baseUrl and port in your [configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Options) (cypress.json), and you can access it using:

```
Cypress.config('port') or Cypress.config().port
```

Comment: The port is generated at runtime. So before making the base URL dynamic, I have run the base ulr along with the port from `package.json` using script. Now I need to move the base URL to spec file , IN that case, I am not getting the right port that app listened ,So its throwing the error .